# Extract the text from a Range to use as the name of a document

Tags: vba, ms-word, range

I have found a macro that searches for a Heading1 format and splits my Word document based on that tag.
I want to extract the text from the H1 tag and use that to name the document - I can Debug print the text but I cannot get it to convert to a string.
Im sure its really simple but I cannot get it to work.

Here is my Macro as it stands (kudos to the original author) - It currently asks for a new name for the docs and uses that, I want to replace the ans$ with a string in the naming function

```
``
Sub Hones()
    Dim aDoc As Document
    Dim bDoc As Document
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim Ans$
    Dim Foundtext As String
    
    Ans$ = InputBox("Enter Filename", "Incremental number added")
    If Ans$ <> "" Then
    
    Set aDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set Rng1 = aDoc.Range
    Set Rng2 = Rng1.Duplicate
    
    Do
    With Rng1.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Forward = True
        .Format = True
        .Style = "Heading 1"
        .Execute
    End With
    
    If Rng1.Find.Found Then
    
        Foundtext = Rng1.Find.Found
        Debug.Print Foundtext

        Counter = Counter + 1
        Rng2.Start = Rng1.End + 1
        With Rng2.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Forward = True
        .Format = True
        .Style = "Heading 1"
        .Execute
        End With
        
        If Rng2.Find.Found Then
            
            Rng2.Select
            Rng2.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Rng2.MoveEnd wdParagraph, -1
            Set Rng = aDoc.Range(Rng1.Start, Rng2.End)
            
            Set bDoc = Documents.Add
            bDoc.Content.FormattedText = Rng
            
            bDoc.SaveAs Counter & ". " & Ans$ & ".docx", 16
            'bDoc.SaveAs Counter & ". " & Foundtext & ".docx", wdFormatDocumentDefault
            bDoc.Close
            Else
            'This collects from the last Heading 1 to the end of the document.
            If Rng2.End < aDoc.Range.End Then
                Set bDoc = Documents.Add
                Rng2.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                Rng2.MoveEnd wdParagraph, -2
                Set Rng = aDoc.Range(Rng2.Start, aDoc.Range.End)
                bDoc.Content.FormattedText = Rng
                'bDoc.SaveAs Counter & ". " & Foundtext & ".docx", wdFormatDocumentDefault
                bDoc.SaveAs Counter & ". " & Ans$ & ".docx", wdFormatDocumentDefault
                bDoc.Close
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    Loop Until Not Rng1.Find.Found
    
    'This is closing End If from Ans$
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I do something similar. It would be simpler if your range were a Bookmark, a Content Control, or even a legacy FormField. My current code extracts from a Content Control and I would be happy to share it.

Comment: I haven't run your code, but rng1.Find.Found is a Boolean, not a string. Try Foundtext = rng1.Text instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the string contained a return at the end of it which the SaveAs function did not like

I replaced this

```
Foundtext = Rng1.Find.Found
Debug.Print Foundtext
```

with this

```
ftext = CStr(Rng1.Text)
namelength = Len(ftext)
Foundtext = Left(ftext, namelength - 2)
```

to trim the end off